# Getting the count of rows in a Java resultset

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Does anyone know a better way of getting the number of rows in a Java resultset returned from a MySQL database? The resultset returned is not going to be the total number of rows read from the database so I don't think I can use SQL's `COUNT` aggregate function.

```
public static int getResultSetRowCount(ResultSet resultSet) {
    int size = 0;
    try {
        resultSet.last();
        size = resultSet.getRow();
        resultSet.beforeFirst();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return 0;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Calling resultSet.last() will cause the result set to actually iterate over all the records - so it is clearly inefficient. Also it will force all the data to be cached to memory even if you don't need it yet.
Any reason why you said "he resultset returned is not going to be the total number of rows read from the database" ?

Comment: @RonK: Why do you think it will be iterating all over? I couldn't find anything like this in docs.

Comment: @Ronk: The data read from the database table will be a subset of the table's data only rather than all the data in the table.

I am curious about the 'iterating all over' though.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari: I'm not 100% certain of it, I decompiled Oracle's result sets and found out that in the flow of invoking the 'last()' method the 'cacheAllRows()' method is invoked, and that method starts with 'while(resultSet.next())'.
I assume that the MySQL driver won't have something better to do.

Comment: @Mr Morgan: As some of the answers below stated - if you have an SQL that gets the data, you can have the same one to return COUNT() - I don't see a reason why it cannot work.

Comment: That catch clause looks a bit suspicious. I would propagate exceptions but at least i would return -1 in that catch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A better answer is to forget about the number of rows until you've successfully loaded the ResultSet into an object or collection.  You can keep the count of the number of rows with either of those options.

It's important to close ResultSets (and all SQL resources like Connection and Statement) in the narrowest method scope possible.  That means not passing ResultSet out of the persistence layer.  Better to get the number of rows using a Collection size() call.

Stop thinking about databases and start thinking in terms of objects.  Java's an object-oriented language.

Comment: (+1) Of course, you are right. `count()` is perfectly fine for me, but not in this case. We normally do that to achieve pagination thingie.

Comment: I find myself wanting to know the rowcount so I can make an appropriately sized `ArrayList`. I mean, the amortized cost is negligible, but if I can get it right the first time, why not right? :-)

Comment: try-with-resources in modern versions of Java is a good way to ensure that database objects are closed when done.

Answer (score 10):

You can execute

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

immediately after executing your SELECT statement to find the row count.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Could you provide the java code that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 6 you can use the JDBC4ResultSet class which has the getUpdateCount method that returns the number of the lines affected by a SQL Statement even for a Select Statement.

See below the example code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from any_table ...");
JDBC4ResultSet rs = (JDBC4ResultSet)ps.executeQuery();
int rowNumber = rs.getUpdateCount();
```

I hope that this help!

Comment: This doesn't really work with MySQL. All I get is -1 even when there is a row.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `SELECT COUNT()` with the same exact conditions, before making the actual `SELECT`.

Comment: @Mr Morgan: Thats perfactly fine for me. Actually, we do similar thing to achieve pagination. However, we ask specific number of rows in the 2nd query though. But here in your case `duffymo` is very much right. When you already queried the database, why not load that into a List or something.

Comment: I'm currently looking at a 2 dimensional arraylist as per duffymo's idea. Before, I needed the resultset number of rows to work out the size of a 2 dimensional String array.

Comment: Or as I'm trying to access table metadata from the system schema, I can use a class with two fields, column name, column type, and then create an array list of this class. The main point here is to avoid iterating through a result set and this class in a collection should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to this question (since I mostly want the number of records returned to build an array or something similar): Use a collection such as [Vector<T>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) instead.

```
public Vector<T> getRecords(){
   Vector<T> records = new Vector<T>();
   init_conn_and_stmt_and_rs();

   try {
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `something` = 0");
      while(rs.next()){
         // Load the Vector here.
      }
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      close_rs_and_stmt_and_conn();
   }
   return records;
}
```

Clean and simple, no? Works for any size record set returned (no need to know the size before hand) and makes all the `List` methods available.

This has served me well for a time now, but if someone sees a flaw in this, please let me know. Always want to make my practices better, ya know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following way to get the total records in the resultSet:

```
statement = connect.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
resultSet.last();
int count = resultSet.getRow();
System.out.println(count);
```

**count** is the total returned rows for your result set. ;)

Comment: It only works if the resultset is scrollable, and it will iterate over all the record so not very efficient.